# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap is not work properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap in ASP.NET MVC is up-to-date (v4.1.3). When I use dropdown components, it does not work properly!

[image: Here is the result]

Then I use:  and comment out `@Style.Render(~/Content/css)`

It goes like this:

[image: Result]

How could I fix this? (I have checked carefully the version of bootstrap in Content folder. It have no problems. As the same as the latest one I download from getbootstrap.com

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and check for errors

Answer (score 1):

today when I open my project, it's css style went wrong. Navbar is not show the style. Then I detected that bootstrap 4.1.3 (lastest version) is not supported with the auto-created layout of ASP.NET MVC (it is now using 3.3.7 as I remember). I think that I should edit the class style. But last, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bootstrap or jQuery reference is not being read. Check your raw html output (right click on webpage and view page as source. Note Bootstrap requires jQuery.

Here is an example of a jQuery and bootstrap order loading on html page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```